# asp.net core app error occurred to build Docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dockerfile

I am using visual studio 2017 professional and Asp.net core app occurred error during the build app, although docker is switched to windows container and enabled Docker support OS : Windows
here is error message

[image]

> An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image

Comment: what is the actual error ? This message could mean anything

Comment: The error is  An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image when I run the app

Comment: what about trying to build the docker image manually in order to get more information about the actual build error ?

Comment: there is an open issue similar to yours: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2825

Comment: Just I see that error no any one

Comment: Could you show Build output?

Comment: Check if the port is already allocated. Always check your Build output. It will have the error specified for example: `Bind for 0.0.0.0:44399 failed: port is already allocated.`

Comment: I my case, Because I live in Iran and the docker is restricted for us, I changed my IP address via a VPN, and it worked.